# python how to sort a list of list of int, str

Tags: python

Given a list of list of int, str, I need to find a way to sort this from highest to lowest, without using sorted. 
So if I have:

```
list = [[1, 'orange'], [3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple']]
```

I should have returned this sorted by number, and if numbers are same, by alphabetical order such as:

```
[[3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple'], [1, 'orange']]
```

is there a way to do this without using the sorted function?

Comment: well, you can use `sort` to sort in place, instead of `sorted` which returns the sorted list without modifying the input.. but why does it matter what function you use?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this without using the sorted function.

Comment: What have you tried? The restrictions suggest this is homework, and if you've been assigned this as homework, you've probably already received an assignment to write a sorting function. If this is the case, it'd be helpful to show us the sort you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use the [`sort()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
lst = [[1, 'orange'], [3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple']]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))

lst
=> [[3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple'], [1, 'orange']]
```

If *that* method isn't allowed either, you could write your own sorting procedure with the corresponding comparator:

```
def compare(x, y):
    return -cmp(x[0], y[0]) or cmp(x[1], y[1])

def quicksort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    return (quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if compare(x, lst[0]) <  0])
            + [lst[0]] + 
            quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if compare(x, lst[0]) >= 0]))

quicksort([[1, 'orange'], [3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple']])
=> [[3, 'banana'], [2, 'pear'], [1, 'apple'], [1, 'orange']]
```

Comment: Could you explain this code `key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1])`, i don't understand.

Comment: @BlackMamba it's a comparison key that says: let's sort the items as if they were tuples, reversing the order for the first element's comparisons and preserving the order for the second element's comparisons. That's convenient, because tuples get sorted first by their first element, in case of a tie by the second element and so on